# print such kind of String in jsp

Tags: jsp

suppose I have a String, say:

```
<abc>
<xyz>
```

How do I print this in JSP? I have tried it,but anything between <> is supposed to be a tag and hence is not printed. Plus,to print it in two new lines also.

To make it more specific:
It's a String that I'm fetching from a previous page and then printing the String using `out.print();` .

Comment: [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSTL: `<c:out escapeXml="true" value="${yourVariable}">`

JSP: Use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.1/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html): `<%=StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(yourVariable)%=>`

HTML: Use `<pre>`: `<pre><%=yourVariable%></pre>`

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape [predefinied HTML/XML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML) when you want to display them as-is in the HTML/XML output. The `<` and `>` are one of them. You need to escape them by `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively.

So,

```
&lt;abc&gt;
&lt;xyz&gt;
```

should do.

Or if it is been obtained as a bean property, use JSTL `<c:out>` or `fn:escapeXml()`.

```
<c:out value="${bean.property}" />
```

or

```
${fn:escapeXml(bean.property)}
```

It will automatically escape them then.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
&lt;abc&gt;<br/>
&lt;xyz&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
out.print("&lt;abx&gt;");
out.print("&lt;xyz&gt;");
```